# Using View to Update Values of Original Table

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access

The title pretty much says it all.

I have a view `vPersonalInfo` that is connected to table `Customers`, which queries a specific part of the original table. I want to be able to alter the view and get results in the `Customers` table.

Is this possible? If not, are there alternatives? Thanks in advance.

Note: I'm using Access to display the info from the `vPersonalInfo` view on a form.

For example, I have this original table called `Customers`:

```
+----+------+----------+
| id | name | isActive |
+----+------+----------+
|  1 | Joe  |        0 |
|  2 | Mike |        1 |
|  3 | Will |        1 |
+----+------+----------+
```

I created a view called `vPersonalInfo` specifically located in Will's database:

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| id |  name  |  isActive |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  3 |   Will |         1 |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

The form in Access is querying `vPersonalInfo`, and I want to alter the value of `isActive` to 0 through the form in Access, so that it will alter the original table's value.

Comment: What do you mean by *"Will's database"*? Are you working with two separate databases? When you refer to a 'View', since you are using MS Access, I'm assuming that you mean 'Query'? Unless you are referring to a View in SQL Server which is linked in MS Access?

Comment: Each customer has a specific database made for him (the structure is similar between all of them), and there is a master database containing the Customer table. And yes, I linked the view from SQL Server to Access, so that it will query the View when opening the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `left join`:

```
select c.id, c.name,
       nz(pi.isActive, c.isActive) as isActive
from customers as c left join
     vPersonalInfo as pi
     on c.id = pi.id;
```